# e-commerce database design(is-a relationship): which is better?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I am designing a e-commerce database model. Right now, I am implementing OrderItem(or OrderLine) table between Order and Item tables. My business model is a online pharmacy, meaning an item in the Item is **either** a prescribed-pills-set or a ready-made product.

Let me clarify on this with a simple diagram.

P.S. I'm building the system in python-django environment, which doesn't support compound natural keys, so I had to set auto-increment id for every table.

### Scenario A

[image]
Things to consider:

- Constraints on OrderItem table's PrescribedPillSet_id & ReadyMadeProduct_id on being mutually exclusive. (if one of the two column is not null, then the other one has to be null)

### Scenario B

[image]

Things to consider:

- Item_id has to be unique.
- OrderItem table checks if an item is a product first. If true, then item with the right item_id from the ReadyMadeProduct table is saved in OrderItem. If false, item from the PrescribedPillsSet is saved.

### Summary

Which do you think is better, performance-wise?
I have a feeling scenario B is a better choice, because it "seems" more explicit to me, but I can't really back it up with evidence.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: If there is no way to make `ReadyMadeProducts` and `PrescribedPillsSet` share a table, I would personally go for option A here. It's *very* confusing to have a field that can refer to two separate tables. I would know because I occasionally support an old app where the original coder went with such a solution. Also, in B you cannot have a foreign key defined on `item_id` in OrderItem so referential integrity is not guaranteed. You could perhaps also have two separate `OrderItem` tables, one for ReadyMadeProducts and one for PrescribedPillSets.

Comment: @user1429080 Thanks. I agree with you. I'll go with the option A. :)